# How to overcome the limitations with mongoDB aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The aggregation framework on MongoDB has certain limitations as per [this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/#limitations).

I want to remove the restrictions 2, 3.

I really do not care what the resulting set's size is. I have a lot of RAM and resources.

And I do not care if it takes more than 10% system resources.

I expect both 2, 3 to be violated in my application. Mostly 2.

But I really need the aggregation framework. Is there anything that I can do to remove these limitations?

- The reason *

The application I have been working has these things

1. The user has the ability to upload a large dataset
2. We have a menu to let him sort, aggregate etc
3. The aggregate has no restrictions currently and the user can choose to do whatever he wants. Since the data is not known to the developer and since it is possible to group by any number of columns, the application can error out.

Choosing something other than mongodb is a no go. We have already sunk too much into development with MongoDB

Is it advisable to change the source code of Mongo?

Comment: It's open source. Although the result size issue will be difficult to overcome. Honestly, without more information, there isn't a good answer. I'd suggest you consider a database that fits your requirements better.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the database - I would consider whether your schema is correct for your use case if you are expecting to rely on functionality that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

1) Saving aggregated values directly to some collection(like with MapReduce) will released in future versions, so first solution is just wait for a while :)

2) If you hit 2-nd or 3-rd limitation may you should redesign your data scheme and/or aggregation pipeline. If you working with large time series, you can reduce number of aggregated docs and do aggregation in several steps (like MapReduce do). I can't say more concretely, because I don't know your data/use cases(give me a comment).

3) You can choose different framework. If you familiar  with MapReduce concept, you can try Hadoop(it can use MongoDB as data source). I don't have experience with MongoDB-Hadoop integration, but I mast warn you **NOT** to use Mongo's MapReduce -- it sucks hard on large datasets.

4) You can do aggregation inside your code, but you should use some "lowlevel" language or library. For example, pymongo (http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) is not suitable for such things, but you can tray something like monary(https://bitbucket.org/djcbeach/monary/wiki/Home) to efficiently extract date and NumPy or Pandas to aggregate it the way want.

Comment: Will look into the libraries mentioned by you. Thanks

Comment: It seems that you have huge problem with design, not with MongoDB. Crunching MongoDB sources is not an option, because it's easier to write your own solution like I said in point 4.

Comment: splitting single document into two and applying linkage seems like RDBMS which breaks the whole concept of nosql, schema-less !where you would require to apply joins for retrieving !